# Increase the max length of the URL in Squid3

Tags: squid

I am looking for a solution to increase the maximum allowed URLs for the Squid3 Proxy. I am getting the following error:

```
Some aspect of the requested URL is incorrect.</p>\n\n<p>Some possible problems are:</p>\n<ul>\n<li><p>Missing or incorrect access protocol
```

The URL I am passing is valid, just the length is too short. If I pass in less parameters everything seems to be working fine.

I read somewhere that I could recompile squid with a max url length. Is there any other config option that I don't know of?

Thank you!

Comment: What I did is, just reduce the amount of records I send through the proxy. More than a workaround than a solution though.

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to this post:[Re: [squid-users] url length limit](http://www.squid-cache.org/mail-archive/squid-users/200811/0163.html#start)

As mentioned in the post above, the default limit is 8192 bytes. I tested on squid/3.3.8 and it is true.
If you need to increase this value, you can change MAX_URL to 16384 in defines.h, and "It's been tested up to 32KB."(Refer to this post:[Re: [squid-users] Modifying MAX_URL](http://www.squid-cache.org/mail-archive/squid-users/201005/0279.html))